# 500 error on fresh Apache setup on Fedora 23. One file loads, and the other doesn't

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, fedora, php

Alright, I'm finding this slightly bizarre.

So, most of my experience with Apache has been on an Ubuntu server install. But after my server's harddrive experienced a catastrophic failure (which I recovered all data from, thankfully) I took the opportunity to switch to the latest Fedora server. There were a few reasons for this, but the big one was problems with the Ubuntu Server installer, specifically it being unable to recognise my wireless keyboard, and my last wired keyboard breaking.

Anyway, I installed httpd (apache), php, postgresql, and php-pgsql. And then I moved all my old site pages to the new web directory (/var/www/html/). Then I got a 500 error.

I decided on a lark to start from scratch. Moved my webpages to the side (into /var/www/html2/), and created a small page to test it. Just basic HTML, nothing fancy, no PHP, just the basics.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HOME!!!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>THIS WORKS!!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

It loaded without issue.

Then I moved every page back to the main folder (with the exception of .htaccess for now), and the page I just created still worked fine. Suspecting the problem was with php, I added a bit of php code to the bottom:

```
echo 'hello';
```

Worked fine.

Here's where it gets weird. I tried including the old footer.php from my site into this little testing page, and that's where the problems start. The footer simply won't load.

```
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

The rest of the page loads, just not the footer. Then, on a lark, I copied all the contents of footer file into a new file called footer2.php and changed the test page to reference footer2.php instead, and it loads entirely without a hitch.

So I finally think I'm onto something, so I change the permissions of footer.php to match footer2.php. And it still won't load.

For some reason, footer.php won't load, but footer2.php will.

So what's the differential!?

These files are exactly the same! Here's proof:

```
[blackwidower@Twilight html]$ md5sum footer*
257cbd773ed765deb5ad0015852cdf20  footer2.php
257cbd773ed765deb5ad0015852cdf20  footer.php
[blackwidower@Twilight html]$ ls -l footer*
-rw-rw-r--. 1 blackwidower blackwidower 1271 Feb  1 00:08 footer2.php
-rw-rw-r--. 1 blackwidower blackwidower 1271 Feb  1 00:08 footer.php
```

Yet one loads, and the other doesn't.

Is there something I can do to find any further data that could separate these files?

For reference, here is the apache error_log:

```
[Mon Feb 01 00:14:15.160242 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1800] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Mon Feb 01 00:14:15.161310 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 1800] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.7.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Feb 01 00:14:15.192180 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1800] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Feb 01 00:14:15.192361 2016] [http2:warn] [pid 1800] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Mon Feb 01 00:14:15.193015 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1800] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Feb 01 00:14:15.218713 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1800] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Fedora) PHP/5.6.17 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 01 00:14:15.218762 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1800] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Feb 01 00:14:43.969957 2016] [:error] [pid 1801] [client 192.168.7.7:49878] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function displayCopyrightInfo() in /var/www/html/footer2.php on line 13
[Mon Feb 01 00:14:44.086110 2016] [core:error] [pid 1802] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.7.7:49880] AH00035: access to /images/cc-by-nc-nd-88x31.png denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html/images/cc-by-nc-nd-88x31.png') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://192.168.7.2/index2.php
[Mon Feb 01 00:14:44.087064 2016] [core:error] [pid 1804] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.7.7:49882] AH00035: access to /images/valid-xhtml10-blue.png denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html/images/valid-xhtml10-blue.png') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://192.168.7.2/index2.php
[Mon Feb 01 00:14:44.087737 2016] [core:error] [pid 1806] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.7.7:49884] AH00035: access to /images/vcss-blue.png denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html/images/vcss-blue.png') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://192.168.7.2/index2.php
[Mon Feb 01 00:15:47.538488 2016] [:error] [pid 1808] [client 192.168.7.7:49890] PHP Warning:  include(footer.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/index2.php on line 7
[Mon Feb 01 00:15:47.538534 2016] [:error] [pid 1808] [client 192.168.7.7:49890] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'footer.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/index2.php on line 7
```

EDIT:

On one person's advice. I ran ls -Z. Here's what I found:

```
unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/html/footer2.php
               system_u:object_r:fusefs_t:s0 /var/www/html/footer.php
```

So I found a differential. Question is: What does this mean, and how does one correct it?

Comment: If you are running SELinux, please add the output of `ls -lZ footer*.php`. You might see that contexts of files are different. If they are equal, I have not better idea for now.

Answer (score 2):

> So I found a differential. Question is: What does this mean, and how
>   does one correct it?

Expanding on what user @Dirk noted, SELinux is a system which relies on "contexts" to increase the security of your system, a context describes what kind of actions can be performed on a certain file or directory or what can a file be used for. In this case, `footer2.php` has a context of `httpd_sys_content_t`, so it means that file can be used for "*http purposes*", what you need to do is add the same context label to `footer.php` in order to let it be accessible through the SELinux security system, or just restore the context on the parent directory (on most systems by default, files in the `/var/www` location are set to labels for "*http purposes*"). An alternative to this is disabling SELinux altogether, but this is not a good practice.

So,

To (permanently) set the context label on the `footer.php` file:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/footer.php
restorecon /var/www/html/footer.php
```

You can do the same on the parent directory (and all of its contents):

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/var/www/html(/.*)?"
restorecon -R "/var/www/html(/.*)?"
```

You can find more information on the [Red Hat Customer Portal for Security-Enhanced Linux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked on every file in the html directory. However,  there's one issue: For one of my hand-written applications (an automated video stream) I have a symbolic link leading directly to my home folder for convenience. And now, I can't seem to change the context for that one directory. I can for the link to the directory, but not the directory itself. Do you know what's going on?

Comment: Thanks for not recommending disabling SELinux, and showing how to actually do the right thing! If you're running a PHP app on any network-accessible server, SELinux is an important added layer of protection.

Comment: @theblackwidower See http://serverfault.com/questions/177061/how-do-i-assign-an-selinux-label-to-a-symlink-with-semanage-so-it-persists-after for SELinux and symlinks. Note that you may need to change a few other things in order to allow Apache to follow that symlink and to server content from there.

Comment: @theblackwidower yes, as @mattdm noted, you have to tweak selinux labels and booleans a little further, like allowing http-serving daemons to access files in home dirs: `setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs=1`